# Lightbox doesn't work in PHP, load like normal instead

Tags: javascript, php, function, lightbox

I' trying to create a lightbox where when you click on *Login*, a lightbox will popup. Here is my code.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo '<a onclick="javascript:displaylightbox({width:500,height:660,centerOnScroll:true,overlayOpacity:0.6})" href="./database/login.php" target="_self">Login</a>';
}?>
```

The link works, but the lightbox doesn't popup. Link load like normal instead.

Here is the function

```
<script>function displaylightbox(url, options)
{
options.padding = 0;
options.autoScale = true;
options.href = url;
options.type = 'iframe';
$.fancybox(options);
}
</script>
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `javascript:` is not needed inside `onclick` (it acts as a label instead, serving no purpose here), and where is `function displaylightbox(..)` defined?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Edited is the functions

Comment: please post the code of displaylightbox too

Comment: You did not call the url in the onclick. You should not set the a href if you want to redirect using Javascript

Comment: I've tried `<a onclick="displaylightbox("./database/login.php",({width:500,height:660,centerOnScroll:true,overlayOpacity:0.6})" target="_self">Login</a>` and the link won't load at all.

Comment: You are not calling `event.preventDefault()` or using `return false;` in the handler. So it's running, but then immediately taking you to the link's target.